# Can i use 2 heartbeat cluster in the same network

Tags: ubuntu, heartbeat

I'm playing with HeartBeat. I'm trying to create 2 clusters with 2 nodes each in the same network.

ldap1 (192.168.3.1) <-> ldap2 (192.168.3.2)
www1 (192.168.3.3)  <-> www2 (192.168.3.4)

With ldap1,ldap2 on and www1,www2 off , HA work
with ldap1,ldap2 off and www1,www2 on. HA work
with ldap1.ldap2 on and www1,www2 on, HA doesn't work.

I have the error:

```
ERROR: netstring authentication failed
```

Can i have 2 HA clusters working in the same network ?

Comment: i know with pfsense and CARP you can have two failover IPs, connected to 2 pools of physical hosts, on same subnet, because each carp "pool" has an authentication string that associates it to its corresponding VIP.  dunno bout heartbeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You will need to configure different multicast addresses in the Heartbeat configurations (/etc/ha.d/ha.cf), or use unicast addresses.

Example config using unicast (mcast commented out):

```
# Only allow the nodes specified in to the cluster
autojoin none

# Use hostnames output by 'uname -n'
node node-a node-b

# Specify the method, interfaces, and addresses for heartbeat communication.
# Depending upon the network configuration this section may need to be different
# on each host (listing only the local interfaces and addresses); however
# Heartbeat should be smart enough to determine which interfaces are local
# and which belong to a peer
udpport 694
ucast eth0 172.17.2.50
ucast eth0 172.17.2.51
ucast eth1 172.18.2.50
ucast eth1 172.18.2.51

# Or, use mcast
# mcast eth0 239.0.0.1 694 1 0
# mcast eth1 239.0.0.1 694 1 0

# Specify where to log to
logfacility syslog

# Thresholds (in seconds)
keepalive 2
warntime 10
deadtime 30
initdead 120
```